# How do I find out why my Xamarin Forms app has stopped receiving push notifications?

Tags: android, ios, azure, xamarin, notifications

I'm looking for some advice, I built a cross-platform mobile app using Xamarin Forms.  It's currently public in both the app store for iOS and Google Play for Android.  Most people are using it without any problems but some people have reported that they have stopped receiving push notifications from it.  Not everyone is experiencing this problem and there seems to be no exact reasoning behind it.

The push notifications are handled on Azure using the Notification Hub.  My first stop was to check this area and try to find any errors during the push notification sending.  Nothing has been reported, I extended this investigation by logging a call with Microsoft Support who reverted with the same conclusion, no errors.

Since the notification hub seems to be working ok, I looked at the users phones.  All devices have their operating systems up to date although, this didn't seem to have an affect as other phones that were up to date still receive the notifications without problems.

I looked at their settings on their phones to ensure they were not in airplane mode, set to dnd or had notification stiched off.  All devices where set up correctly.

So I'm now confused and looking for other avenues to investigate.  It could very well be the app but it's odd that the majority of users don't have the problem, it's only one or two.  What can I check next?

Comment: Are those users are constant? or  changing time to time? Means to particular users only not going or to any of two among many?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question but, the users experiencing problems are the same one all the time.  The notifications are sent out to many people and only a couple are not receiving them.

Comment: Do you have the Google registration token of any of those devices?

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm not coming to the conclusion on your problem as I don't know how you have implemented. But from your question, I'm assuming this.

1. If same users not getting notifications every time, make sure that push notification ID you are getting for that particular users is working or not. To test that, get their push notification id and try any tool like **PUSHER** to test notification on that device. Check it's getting success or not.
2. Second in case, if it's changing from users to users, for an example, when notifications are going in bulk, if A & B are not getting, next time when notifications sent out, if C & D are not getting, then sending too many notifications at a single point in time is problem. If you send too many notifications at a time, there are chances for few dropping out due to network or any other reasons. In that scenario, you should send notifications in 2, 3 time intervals.

Comment: Is there any way I can find out a particular person registration token?  Some of the app users and external and some are internal to my company.  Of those who are internal, two have the problem so if I could find their registration token that would help.  Obviously, it's hard to correlate a token to a phone.

Comment: I think you should start to accept that parameter in the server database, whenever a user logs in. It will help you in future also.